# ServiceStack Swagger-UI repeating

Tags: servicestack, swagger

Using ServiceStack's SwaggerFeature, I'm seeing all of my routes repeated on the Swagger documentation page. Under each "/v1" node, all of my endpoints are repeated for each "/v1". I have configured ServiceStack as listed on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API . Any idea why these would all be repeated?

[image]

Update : This has been fixed in an updated version of ServiceStack

Comment: Hey Rob, can you create an issue with stub outlines of the DTO's you're using on https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues

Answer (score 1):

Another potential cause for duplicate routes in Swagger is inheriting DTO classes.

Inheritance for DTO classes should be avoided.